# How to clean up and create a Archiving strategy for a folder on Github

Tags: github, github-actions, liquibase

I have

- A git repository
- A folder on this repository
- To this folder I upload .SQL files. A new DDL is a new .SQL file and it is uploaded to the same folder as this is the place from which a CICD process kicks off to act upon this new file. I do change the sql code now and then but have no use for them after a certain point as it gets executed to the ultimate database via Liquibase

The Problem

- Over time this folder now has close to 5000 .SQL files and growing everyday
- Its getting cumbersome to navigate and find anything in this folder
- The CICD build out of this folder is taking a lot of time it zips the entire folder

I want to

- Archive/Remove everything more than 3 months old from the main folder
- Move the old files to an Archived location so that I can refer to them
- Get the file count down to a manageable level
- Possibly do the archiving in a automated way without manual intervention

I Do not want to

- Delete the files as I have to maintain a history
- Change the process as may be have only one sql file and keep changing it.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want Delete the files as I have to maintain a history

And yet, this is the simplest solution, as you still [list the history of a deleted file](https://gist.github.com/hienvd/f6b8e8dd8a2050344e73ba8e728a614e).

```bash
# filter the deleted file to find one:
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep pattern_to_search

# Find the log of a deleted file:
git log --all -- FILEPATH
```

That means your process would simply:

- list all files older than a certain date
- add their name to a "catalog" file (in order to query them easily later on)
- delete (`git rm`) them (their history is still there

For any file present in the "catalog" file, you still can check their log with:

```
git log -- a/deleted/file
```